# Grab and save image from url to Craft?

Tags: image

I have a cool upcoming project which its content will heavily depend on external images. Although I'd like to get rid of WordPress for this project and would love to use Craft, WP has a great plugin called [Grab & Save](https://wordpress.org/plugins/save-grab/), that allows you to grab and save images from remote urls into your own WP media library.

I was wondering if Craft has a similar plugin or functionality, which it would be a huge time saver for these kind of projects.

**-Edit**

Without wanting to sound cheeky, would anyone with a bit of free time care to help me out a noobie and write it for me? I can't make head or tail of programming :/ heh.

Comment: I'm sure there are developers willing to take on this project as a contract job (read: get paid). A great place to advertise for your Craft project is on the [Straight Up Craft - Jobs Board](http://straightupcraft.com/jobs).

Answer (score 1):

Until the plugin store officially becomes a thing, the most up-to-date list of plugins available for Craft is [here](http://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins).

I'm not seeing anything that does exactly what you're looking for and Craft doesn't have that functionality natively, but it doesn't seem like too difficult of a plugin to write.

Comment: Ah, didn't know about that site! Thank you @Brad-Bell. Without wanting to sound cheeky, would anyone with a bit of free time care to help me out a noobie and write it for me? I can't make head or tail of programming :/ heh.